# this pointer is shown as a variable name in eclipse while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, this

Below is the screen shot of eclipse while I was trying to debug my program. I could not understand why the variables section in the top right corner shows "this" as a variable name and the value of this as Test(class name). I always thought this is a pointer and not a variable.

can anyone help me with this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why is it strange for `this` to be a variable? `this` can be thought of as being a pointer and a variable at the same time. A pointer in the abstract sense that it points to some memory location. A variable in the sense that it has a name assigned to it (the name just happens to be `this`)

Comment: There are no pointers in Java.

Answer (score 0):

"this" it is a  keyword reference to the current object. It is used to pass this instance of the object..

For example, these two allocations are equal:

```
class Test{

    int i;

    public Test(){

    }
         public void abc(int i){
                i++;
        this.i++;
}

}
```

and your program doesn't make any sense to me ...

Comment: What do you mean by "these two allocations are equal"?

Comment: i mean i++ or this.i++ both are equal... kindly correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You're wrong, one is the parameter, one is the instance variable.

Comment: in the program object is not created. if you observe properly you can see that. it just entered the main function and the first statement is creating an object so it just searched for constructor. it did not enter the constructor yet. so it cant be the current object reference

Comment: @MrsB Sure it can. And obviously it is.